# UITableViewCell gets duplicated after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Although there are some questions already being asked about this problem, I can't seem to fix mine. Problem is that when I scroll or reload my UITableView the cells duplicate. I know the problem has something to do with reusing of the cells. Here's a screenshot of what's going wrong:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXAcy.jpg

Here's the code I use to customize the appearance of the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellID = @"DividendCell";

DividendCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil)
{        
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:cellID bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellID];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
}

dividend *div = [[[aAgendaItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] agendaItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setDiv:div];

return cell;
```

}

I use a Xib for the custom cell.

Hope anyone could help me out!

EDIT:

This is the code for the setDiv method to apply data to row:

```
-(void)setDiv:(dividend *)div {
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[div RelatedIssue] ShortName] capitalizedString]];
[issueName setText:text];
[text release];

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[div Description]];
[issueType setText:text];
[text release];

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[div Currency]];
[issueCurrency setText:text];
[text release];

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[super formatDouble:[div BrutValue]]];
[issueKoers setText:text];
[text release];

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *loc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"nl_NL"];
[format setLocale:loc];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd MMM"];

text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[format stringFromDate:[div ExDividendDate]]];
[exDividendDate setText:text];
[text release];

NSComparisonResult result = [[div PaymentDate] compare:[NSDate date]];
text = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[format stringFromDate:[div PaymentDate]]];
if (result==NSOrderedAscending) {
    [exPaymentDate setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
} else {
    [exPaymentDate setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
[exPaymentDate setText:text];
[text release];
[loc release];
```

}

Comment: In your setDiv method, make sure you remove anything that may already be on the cell.  Also why are you dequeueing twice?

Comment: Show the code for `setDiv` or any methods it calls. Looks like you are adding subviews to the table view cells in the setDiv method or something similar.

Comment: Don't you add the subviews (`UILabel`) in `[cell setDiv:div];` ?

Comment: You don't need to call `registerNib` every time. Just call it in the `viewDidLoad` for example, then you won't have to test if `cell == nil`

Comment: The data for the cell is added in the setDiv method, which is included in the question now. I don't really know how to remove/reset anything that's on the cell...

Comment: Try doing what KIDdAe suggested and see if that fixes the problem. You should move the registerNib line to viewDidLoad, and delete the whole if (cell == nil) clause. You should do this anyway, even if it doesn't fix your problem, because you only need to call registerNib once, not every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: @rdelmar I moved this line to viewDidLoad, but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by trial & error. The solution was to check the checkbox *Clears Graphics Context* under *View* > *Drawing* in the *Attributes Inspector* for the specific labels. I noticed this box wasn't checked for the labels that where overlapping each other. Really strange imo. But happy I fixed it after a week of getting crazy.

Answer (score 4):

Because the cells are being reused, that means that all subviews in the cells are getting reused, too. You need to set or reset anything that ends up getting displayed in the cell.

For example, if you have a UILabel "subtitle" that gets set for some cells and not for others, you must make sure to `[subtitle setText:@""]` if it's an empty or nil value, or `[subtitle setText:realValueString]` if it has a legitimate value. If you do not, the subview from the "old" cell will continue to have it's old value and be displayed in your "new" cell.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. See my edited post. I added the code for the setDiv method in which I apply the data to the cell.

Comment: @djsmit Is the label being "written over" one of `issueName`, `issueType`, `issueCurrency`, `issueKoers`, `exDividendDate`, or `exPaymentDate`? If not, you need to set that everytime the cell is requested as well.

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean. If you scroll down some rows are already duplicated. If you scroll back up all of the cells are duplicated. Check the link to the screenshot. Do you have an example on how to reset the values for reused cells?

Comment: @djsmit What is the variableName of the UILabel that is seemingly being overwrote/duplicated/messed-up?

Comment: All of them are. issueName, issueType, issueCurrency, issueKoers, exDividendDate & exPaymentDate. Check this image to see what's going wrong: http://imgur.com/JrnERSD

Comment: This is a common issue with reusing cells. Here's a brute-force way to approach this problem: implement `- (void)prepareForReuse` on your cell. In that method set **every one** of the cell's UILabel's (or images, or textfields, or whatever) to a clean or obnoxiously obvious default value, e.g. @"" or @"OMG NOT RESET" for UILabel's text property, or bright orange bg for any images that must be reset. Now, after the cell is dequeued, and your `- (void)setDiv` method is invoked, if everything doesn't look perfectly reset, or if the bright orange shows through, the problem likely lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I tried to reset the label in the prepareForReuse method. I also moved the registerNib line to viewDidLoad. To no success, unfortunately. Even if I just assign the UILabel in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, the cells get duplicated. I have no clue that's going on...